# DNS zone servicing concepts

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dns-zone, authoritative

Currently I am working out some concepts about how DNS works and am running into a question I can't easily find an answer to on the internet. I am looking for an answer based on a set of questions regarding the following scenario:

---

Server01.example.local and server02.example.local are both generic DNS (BIND, Windows, etc.) servers. They both live under the impression that they are authoritative primary for the zone `example.local`. There is a working network connection between these two servers.

---

1. First of all; Is this configuration possible? Is it possible to host two R/W copies of a DNS zone?
2. If it is possible, do problems arise as both servers service the zone as R/W primary? Thus instead of having a secondary server.
3. What would happen if the zonedata on both servers for `example.local` would be different and clients get serviced over a virtual IP? This would be a loadbalanced configuration I suppose.

As my mobile phone can't virtualize two DNS servers (as of yet), I can't truely test this. Can someone shed some light on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1/ Yes that is perfectly possible, and this is one of the reasons that registrars and a recognized authorities (IANA, ...) exist for public DNS zones.

2/ There is no real issue with that if you have not done any further configuration. Problems arise when a parent server has to communicate to clients the IP of the server that really "owns" the domain. Technically speaking it is possible to register the domain on both servers *AND* advertise them both, but you could encounter what is called a split-brain configuration: depending on which you are requesting, you might have wrong answers; if server A was updated but not B, a client requesting something from server B would get an inaccurate answer.

3/ See my previous answer. And add several things like: incorrect cache, non DNS-queries (ie. webservers, mail, SIP, ...) failing from time to time with no apparent reason, and many more.

Final point: This configuration should not be done , at least manually. Some tools / professional application allow you to do this but they ensure that everything is correctly replicated to avoid unsolvable issues. If you wanted something resilient, you'd rather go with a Master/Slave configuration and if your master were to die a simple change in the slave's configuration would make it the authority server.